# Using a php script to store an image in a specific folder on a server

Tags: c#, php, winforms

In my application I'm saving an image and transferring to a server through the use of a php script whose sole job is to pass this image to the server which saves it in the root of the server.

The code I have for my upload is as follows:

```
   NameValueCollection nvc = new NameValueCollection();
   nvc.Add("id", "TTR");
   nvc.Add("btn-submit-photo", "Upload");
   UploadToServer.HttpUploadFile(Settings.Default.ServerAddress , sfd.FileName.ToString(), "file", "image/jpeg", nvc);
```

Settings.Default.ServerAddress holds the location of my upload php script which the following:

```
http://server.foo.com/images/upload.php
```

I have another php script that returns a string of all the file and folders held on my server that is returned and displayed in a text box.

I'm calling this like so:

```
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
             result = client.DownloadString("http://server.foo.com/images/getDirectoryList.php");
        }
```

What I need to do is have a way so that I can choose the location of where the my image is stored. My feeling is telling that I need to do is have a way so that when a user selects anything with .folder, the old string list disappears and the images and files is stored within that folder.

I believe the call I need to make is something like this:

```
http://server.foo.com/images/getDirectoyList.php?dir=test_folder
```

But I'm stuck on trying to implement what I want. For one, the list I get back is all highlight and say I get something like

> Image 1
>
> Image 2
>
> Test_folder.folder

I have no way of being able to simply click on Image 2 and have it highlight the whole thing. Instead is simply places the cursor where I clicked. Likewise I have no idea of how I would pass this information over to the my upload code so that my chosen directory is used to store the image as opposed to the root.

Has anyone ever attempted something like this before?
Do you have any links or advice that could help me achieve what it is I want to achieve?
Additionally, but not important, would I be able to ever create a new directory / folder on my server through my C# winform application without having to touch either the php scripts or the server itself?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to expose a server's file system over a network of any kind, especially using home grown mechanisms. You should investigate FTP or WebDav for a more standard solution.

Comment: I have no access to the server or anything like that so I'm afraid those aren't an option. Above is what I need to impliment. Be it good or bad.